# How to enable Memcache in php:5.6-fpm-alpine docker container

Tags: php, docker, memcached

This is error output on `php -m`

> Warning:
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcache.so'
>
> - Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcache.so:
>   No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Dockerfile

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=5.6

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine

RUN apk --update add openssh-client make grep autoconf gcc libc-dev zlib-dev

RUN cd /tmp \
    && curl -o php-memcache.tgz http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-3.0.8.tgz \
    && tar -xzvf php-memcache.tgz \
    && cd memcache-3.0.8 \
    && curl -o memcache-faulty-inline.patch http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/plain/main/php5-memcache/memcache-faulty-inline.patch?h=3.4-stable \
    && patch -p1 -i memcache-faulty-inline.patch \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr \
    && make INSTALL_ROOT=/ install \
    && install -d ./etc/php/conf.d \
    && echo "extension=memcache.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcache.ini
```

docker-compose up -d has no error on execution, the extension is enabled but still missing from the system.

**NOTE**: This is a legacy system working on PHP 5.6 that needs to be dockerized in order to refactor the project to work on PHP 7.x

Project are dependant on **Memcache** and not on **Memcached**

Comment: Hi! Did you succeed?

Comment: @StormI had added an answer and explained the solution.

Answer (score -2):

The problem was the docker **`Memcached`** container, I tried to connect to the Memcached server using memcache.

I was unable to find the **`Memcache`** docker container so **`Memcached`** is used.

```
version: '3.6'

services:
   https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
  php-platform:
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=localhost
    container_name: php-5.6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/5.6/Dockerfile
      cache_from:
        - ./docker/php/5.6/
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - memcached-client
      - gearman
      - rabbitmq
      - mailcatcher
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/dev-docker:rw,cached
      - /usr/local/lib
    extra_hosts:
      - dev-docker.geschenkparadies.ch:host-gateway
    networks:
      - default

  # https://hub.docker.com/_/node/
  nodejs:
    container_name: nodejs
    build:
      context: ./ReactAdmin
      dockerfile: ../docker/nodejs/Dockerfile
      cache_from:
        - ../docker/nodejs
    volumes:
      - ./ReactAdmin:/var/www/dev-docker/ReactAdmin:rw,cached
    networks:
      - default

  # https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/
  web-server:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
      cache_from:
        - ./docker/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php-platform
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/dev-docker:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    networks:
      - default

  # https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql
  db:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci --max-allowed-packet=67108864
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=gp_core
      - MYSQL_USER=gp_sql_local
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3307
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    networks:
      - default

  # https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached
  memcached-client:
    image: memcached:alpine
    container_name: memcached-client
    command: -p 11212
    ports:
      - "11212:11212"
    networks:
      - default

 # http://localhost:15672/#
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabitmq-platform
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/rabitmq/Dockerfile
      cache_from:
        - ./docker/rabitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - default

  gearman:
    image: artefactual/gearmand:latest
    container_name: gearman-platform
    ports:
      - "4730:4730"
    networks:
      - default

  # https://hub.docker.com/r/schickling/mailcatcher/
  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    container_name: mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1026:1025" # changed to 1026 to avoid local instance of mailcatcher
      - "1081:1080"

networks:
  default:
    name: "network"

volumes:
  db-data: { }
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```